# Change in the domain when applying the power rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

The power rule is usually defined as $f'(x) = rx^{r-1}$ if $f(x) = x^r$.

Now if $g(x) = x$, then $D_g = \mathbb{R}$.

By applying the power rule, $g'(x) = 1 \cdot x^0 = 1$, but now $D_{g'} = \mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}$ since $g'(0) = 1 \cdot 0^0$ which is not defined.

The derivative of $g$ should be $g'(x) = 1, x \in \mathbb{R}$ though.

So would a more accurate definition of the power rule for $f(x) = x^r$ be $$\begin{equation}
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
    rx^{r-1} & \text{if }r \neq 1 \\ 
    1 & \text{if }r = 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}, \hspace{1cm} D_{f'} = D_f?$$

Comment: Not really. $x\mapsto g'(x)$ is the constant function to $1$, with perfectly well defined behaviour. There is a difficulty with $0^0$ only because of our deficient need for notation; the actual derivative limit for $g$ at $0$ produces $1$, no problem.

Comment: @FShrike Oh, so it's a notational problem. Thanks